# GridView with ObjectDatasource UpdateMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, devexpress, objectdatasource

I have an ASP.NET WebForms page containing an `ASPxGridView` and an `ObjectDataSource`:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="objDsEmployees"
    KeyFieldName="EmployeeId">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
            <EditButton Visible="True" />
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="EmployeeId" VisibleIndex="1" />
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" VisibleIndex="2" />
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Email" VisibleIndex="3" />
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Telephone" VisibleIndex="5" />
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objDsEmployees"
    runat="server"
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
    DataObjectTypeName="MySite.Data.Models.Employee"
    DeleteMethod="Delete"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original{0}"
    InsertMethod="Insert"
    SelectMethod="GetAll"
    TypeName="MySite.Services.EmployeeService"
    UpdateMethod="Update" />
```

The Employee model contains the following properties:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get;

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

The `ObjectDataSource` calls the `Update` method in the service layer:

```
public void Update(Employee employee, Employee originalEmployee)
{
    _db.Employees.Attach(originalEmployee);
    _db.Entry(originalEmployee).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When the `Update` method is called, the parameters `employee` and `originalEmployee` only contain the properties used as columns in the `ASPxGridView` and the other properties (`Password` for example) are null.

Is there a way I can preserve these values somewhere?
By the way, I use Entity Framework for data access and DevExpress for the GridView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also solve this by setting `ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"` in the `ObjectDataSource`:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objDsEmployees"
    runat="server"
    DeleteMethod="Delete"
    InsertMethod="Insert"
    SelectMethod="GetAll"
    UpdateMethod="Update"
    DataObjectTypeName="App.Core.Domain.Employee"
    TypeName="App.Core.Services.EmployeeService"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original{0}"
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" />
```

Then in the `Update` method in `EmployeeService` we fetch the original employee first by its id, then we merge this original employee with the updated employee. This makes sure that not updated properties don't become null - although it requires an extra call to the database:

```
public void Update(Employee originalEmployee, Employee employee)
{
    // Get the original employee by its id.
    Employee fullOriginalEmployee = GetById(originalEmployee.EmployeeId);

    // Merge the data of the updated employee with the original employee.
    fullOriginalEmployee.Name = employee.Name;
    fullOriginalEmployee.Email = employee.Email;
    fullOriginalEmployee.Telephone = employee.Telephone;
    fullOriginalEmployee.BirthDate = employee.BirthDate;

    // Persist changes in database.
    SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the `ObjectDataSource` to:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource 
    ID="objDsEmployees"
    runat="server"
    DeleteMethod="Delete"
    InsertMethod="Insert"
    SelectMethod="GetAll"
    TypeName="MySite.Services.EmployeeService"
    UpdateMethod="Update">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="employeeId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And the `Update` method in the service layer to:

```
public void Update(int employeeId, string name, string email)
{
    var employee = GetById(employeeId);
    employee.Name = name;
    employee.Email = email;

    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Other solutions are, however, more than welcome!