# Cannot call update function on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource, aspxgridview

I have aproblem everytime I call my update function,
I belive that the source of the problem is because this function gets object paramter,
and also get a paramter from diffrant souce, and i am not doing it currectly.

This is the error:
http://prntscr.com/2z0cd6

GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAnimals" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceAnimals" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="animalId">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="animalId" HeaderText="animalId" SortExpression="animalId" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="vertebrates" HeaderText="vertebrates" SortExpression="vertebrates" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="vegetarian" HeaderText="vegetarian" SortExpression="vegetarian" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="terrestrial" HeaderText="terrestrial" SortExpression="terrestrial" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="kind" HeaderText="kind" SortExpression="kind" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="avgWeight" HeaderText="avgWeight" SortExpression="avgWeight" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="avgHeight" HeaderText="avgHeight" SortExpression="avgHeight" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="infoAdress" HeaderText="infoAdress" SortExpression="infoAdress" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="imageAdress" HeaderText="imageAdress" SortExpression="imageAdress" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceAnimals" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteAnimal" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetAllAnimals" TypeName="BLProject.Animal" UpdateMethod="UpdateAnimal" DataObjectTypeName="BLProject.Animal">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="a" Type="Object" />
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="newsAdress" SessionField="Adress" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textSearch" Name="Search" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dropdownlistAnimalToSearch" Name="type" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="a" Type="Object" />
                    <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="D:\\project\\Ilan Project 29-11\\Web\\NewsInfo" Name="newsAdress" SessionField="Adress" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

*I belive that the source of the error is in the bold lines

The Update function:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
    public static int UpdateAnimal(Animal a, string newsAdress)
```

Animal a is the object paramter which the grid view get by using the select function,
but the adress is another paramter from session source which the function gets too.
However, since I added this paramter I have this new error.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I know, Since I added the new parameter to my function, the gridview also ask me to manually add the object parameter.
However, I dont know how to do it, so I belivet that this is the source of my problem:
"<asp:Parameter Name="a" Type="Object" />"

Comment: Can you check If you add this to your object data source DataObjectTypeName="Animal" ?

Comment: I think i had this:
http://prntscr.com/2z0tv2

*edit: I added this:
http://prntscr.com/2z0ufi

Comment: Thanks, but now I have a new error:
http://prntscr.com/2z0uyf

Comment: The TypeName is not your class name where you have the method update like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19199243/1664356  and from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.dataobjecttypename(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: So what should i write there?
just the name of the class?

Comment: as i understand from that examples, yes should be the name of the class including the namespace.

Comment: Well i did:
http://prntscr.com/2z17u5
However, I have this problem:
http://prntscr.com/2z18tj

Comment: can you update the code in the question?

Comment: TypeName="BLProject.Animal" this is wrong, Update method is inside this class?

Comment: Yes, as u can see in the other code that I put under the title:"The Update function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Change your method with this one

```
public void UpdateAnimal(int animalId, string name, bool vertebrates, bool vegetarian, string newsAdress)
    {

    }
```

and your ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceAnimals" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteAnimal" SelectMethod="GetAllAnimals" TypeName="BLProject.Animal" UpdateMethod="UpdateAnimal">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="a" Type="Object" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="newsAdress" SessionField="Adress" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textSearch" Name="Search" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dropdownlistAnimalToSearch" Name="type" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="animalId" Type="Int32"/>
                .......the other fields from Animal that you want to update
                <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="vegetarian" Type="Boolean"/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="vertebrates" Type="Boolean"/>
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="D:\\project\\Ilan Project 29-11\\Web\\NewsInfo" Name="newsAdress" SessionField="Adress" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Seems that when using `DataObjectTypeName` you cannot add parameters. The solution is to send some or all the properties of the `Animal` row edited as parameters plus the other parameter.

If you want to use `OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"`, add this `int original_animalid` to the method input parameters.

Comment: I changed, but still doesnt work:
http://prntscr.com/2z2mdm

and i also tried to add agian  this:
"DataObjectTypeName="BLProject.Animal"

but i had a new error:
http://prntscr.com/2z2n3g

Comment: Don't add this DataObjectTypeName when you use parameters, and also remove OldValuesParameterFormatString if you don't use it. I tested this code and is working, check again the method parameters types must match with the ones inside Animal class.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but now the delete is not working,
its doesnt send all the parameters, its just send the id of the object.